# Cannot invoke method data Binding() on null object, while adding dataBinding in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding

I searched in stackoverflow a lot i cant find a solution to this particular issue,

i added

```
 dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

inside the android{} and also android support repository is enabled

but  getting this error

Update: using Java

> [image: Cannot invoke method data Binding() on null object]

Comment: If you are using Kotlin you need also add ```apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'``` in your gradle file and ```kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"``` as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not latest plugins, then do update.

Project level gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Also note data binding support greater than 14 version. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start).
So if you are targetting below 14 then don't use data binding.